# How would I enable FTP on home PC (Win7)?

Tags: windows-7, ftp

In my home, all PCs connect through a small router. Some wired and some wireless.

Our Media PC (HTPC) is controlled via a Media Center TV style remote, so managing files on it is tedious.

I can access all of the files on the HTPC from my desktop PC, but moving a 6 GB file from `\\HTPC\Folder1` to `\\HTPC\Folder2` involves copying the data to the desktop and then transferring it back. If I were on the HTPC, this would likely be handled by a simple address change for the file (i.e. it would be done almost instantly).

I'm thinking if I could get an FTP program to connect to the HTPC, I could simplify things

...but how do I enable that ability on the HPTC?

Then, how would I go about connecting to the HTPC? Would I simply enter `\\HTPC` as the FTP address?

Comment: Try this http://www.programmerfish.com/how-to-make-local-ftp-server-in-windows-7/ , This is to run a local FTP server, Make a FTP server on HTPC and access it from other PC via its local IP (like 192.168.1.3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could run a local FTP on the HTPC and access it on the other PC on the same network via its local IP, Instructions for setting up a FTP server can be found in this [LifeHacker post](http://lifehacker.com/130806/how-to-set-up-a-home-ftp-server).

OR if you are running Windows 7 Pro or Ultimate then try following this [ProgrammerFish guide](http://www.programmerfish.com/how-to-make-local-ftp-server-in-windows-7/).

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to setup an FTP to do this. log in as an administrator on both machines. All you need to do is open up windows explorer on the computer you are trying to move the files from and type `\\192.168.XXX.XXX\C$` in the address bar to access the C drive of your HTPC.

**NOTE:** The `192.168.XXX.XXX` would be the IP address of the HTPC. Change the X's.

The IP address is the local IP of your HTPC machine. If you don't know how to get that then go to start and type in CMD in the search bar and press enter. Type `ipconfig` in the black popup box. The address is the one beside the IPv4. Then copy the files just like you normally would between folders.

Answer (score 2):

I've been using filezilla server on my windows 7 machine. Its been my favorite by far.

http://filezilla-project.org/download.php?type=server

there's even a handy how-to here

http://wiki.filezilla-project.org/FileZilla_FTP_Server

hope this helps,

Answer (score 1):

If I recall correctly, that ability is only available in the pro and ultimate editions of windows 7, so you may have to install 3rd party ftp software. There are a number of options out there:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_FTP_server_software